# How do I move an item in one array from another depending on how many items it has?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have four arrays listed below. The first array contains a series of items that need to be moved into one of the remaining three arrays.

The three "trays" can hold no more than 5 items so once I have reached the limit on trayOne, the items should be added to trayTwo and so forth.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

JS

```
var job = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];

var trayOne = [];
var trayTwo = [];
var trayThree = [];
```

Comment: You are expected to try and show what you've tried - this is not a code writing service

Comment: you can try with [Array.slice documentation link](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/slice) if you have fixed size arrays.. give it a try and share your results here..

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = [];
 job.forEach(
  (el,i)=>(result[~~(i/5)]=result[~~(i/5)] || []).push(el)
 );
```

Simply create a 2D array, an assign each job to it.
If youre wondering about this:

```
~~(i/5)
```

That will return 0, for i=0,1,2,3,4, 1 for 6,7,8,9,10 ...

Now you can easily do:

```
var trayOne = result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the single result array in one array and assign then the chunks.

```js
var job = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'],
    trayOne = [],
    trayTwo = [],
    trayThree = [],
    result = [trayOne, trayTwo, trayThree],
    i = 0,
    chunk = 3; // just for example
    
while (i * chunk < job.length) {
    [].push.apply(result[i], job.slice(i * chunk, (i + 1) * chunk));
    i++;
}

console.log(trayOne);
console.log(trayTwo);
console.log(trayThree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: just the peril of blind typing.